# Object of class is nil after init

Tags: ios, objective-c

Before, I want to apologize for my English, I will fix this problem soon ;-)

So, i have an object of class descent from UIView. In initWithFrame I init array with objects, BUT in other method array equal nil. I think that this problem is related to ARC but dont know why and how to fix it.

Please, help for junior developer)

tnx!!

Yes, I use a xib

Code:

```
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

        #import "MYRegistrationView.h"

        @interface MYSelectDayView : UIView <RegisterViewDelegate>

        //property
        @property (strong, nonatomic)          NSNumber *weekday;
        @property (strong, nonatomic)          NSMutableArray  *arrayOfButtons;

        //Buttons
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *mondayButton;
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *tuesdayButton;
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *wednesdayButton;
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *thursdayButton;
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *fridayButton;
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *saturdayButton;
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *sundayButton;

        //Action
        - (IBAction)selectWeekday:(id)sender;

        //methods
        - (void) getDaysOfTraining: (NSArray *) array;



        @end

        #import "MYSelectDayView.h"
        #import "MYRegistrationView.h"

        @implementation MYSelectDayView 

        @synthesize weekday;

        @synthesize arrayOfButtons;

        @synthesize mondayButton;
        @synthesize tuesdayButton;
        @synthesize wednesdayButton;
        @synthesize thursdayButton;
        @synthesize fridayButton;
        @synthesize saturdayButton;
        @synthesize sundayButton;

        - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
        {
            self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
            if (self) {
                // Initialization code
            }

            weekday = [[NSNumber alloc] init];


            mondayButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
            tuesdayButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
            wednesdayButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
            thursdayButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
            fridayButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
            saturdayButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
            sundayButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

            arrayOfButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:mondayButton,
                                                              tuesdayButton,
                                                              wednesdayButton,
                                                              thursdayButton,
                                                              fridayButton,
                                                              saturdayButton,
                                                              sundayButton,      nil];

            return self;
        }

        - (IBAction)selectWeekday:(id)sender {

            weekday =[NSNumber numberWithInt:[sender tag]];

        }

        - (void) getDaysOfTraining: (NSArray *) array {
            for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
                if ([array objectAtIndex:i]==[NSNumber numberWithBool:1]) {
                    [[arrayOfButtons objectAtIndex:i] setEnabled: YES];
                    NSLog(@"1");
                }
                else {
                    [[arrayOfButtons objectAtIndex:i] setEnabled: NO];
                    NSLog(@"0");
                }
            }
            NSLog(@"OK");
        }
        @end
```

Comment: Please add the related code too.

Comment: show the relevant code

Comment: Show both the init method and where you call it (or are you using XIB / storyboard)?

Comment: So where are you creating the instance of the view? The comment `// Initialization code` is where your initialisation code should be (not after the `if`...)

Comment: Thx, guys! You are really help me! And special tnx for Wain

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `IBOutlet` I expect your view is being created in an XIB or a storyboard. As such, `initWithFrame:` will not be called (`initWithCoder:` will be called instead to unarchive the view). You also shouldn't be creating a whole new set of buttons (which have no target / action / title and aren't ever added as subviews).

Remove your `initWithFrame:` and replace with:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.arrayOfButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:mondayButton,
                                                                  tuesdayButton,
                                                                  wednesdayButton,
                                                                  thursdayButton,
                                                                  fridayButton,
                                                                  saturdayButton,
                                                                  sundayButton,
                                                                  nil];
}
```